# Module Our Service Or Featured Project In Template Ja_decor(joomlart)?

Tags: templates, joomla, module, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

Once the modules that I've customized some fields of the featured projects or our service 
Becomes corrupted?

What is the problem?

Does anyone have this trouble?

I also put a photo.

[image]

[image]

thanks

Comment: Try to clear joomla cache and your browser cache.

Comment: Had no effect, on the local host site is currently.

Comment: You have to open module code and try to [trim the string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: The problem was solved.
Template Ja_decor company joomlart.
Only 3 version of Joomla to use.